# ambari cluster + when need to set Block replication to 1

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

We get the following in Spark logs:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try. (Nodes: current=[DatanodeInfoWithStorage DatanodeInfoWithStorage\
The current failed datanode replacement policy is DEFAULT, and a client may configure this via 'dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy' in its configuration.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs

.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.findNewDatanode(DFSOutputStream.java:1036)
```

My Ambari cluster includes only 3 workers machines and each worker have only one data disk.

I searched on Google and found solution can be about block replication. Block replication in HDFS is configured to 3 by default and I found the suggestion to set the "Block replication" to 1 instead of 3.

Question: does it make sense?

Furthermore, can the fact that my worker machine only has one data disk be part of the problem?

> *Block replication = The total number of files in the file system will be what's specified in the dfs.replication factor setting
>   dfs.replication=1, means will be only one copy of the file in the file
>   system.*

**The full log:**

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try. (Nodes: current=[DatanodeInfoWithStorage[34.2.31.31:50010,DS-8234bb39-0fd4-49be-98ba-32080bc24fa9,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[34.2.31.33:50010,DS-b4758979-52a2-4238-99f0-1b5ec45a7e25,DISK]], original=[DatanodeInfoWithStorage[34.2.31.31:50010,DS-8234bb39-0fd4-49be-98ba-32080bc24fa9,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[34.2.31.33:50010,DS-b4758979-52a2-4238-99f0-1b5ec45a7e25,DISK]]). The current failed datanode replacement policy is DEFAULT, and a client may configure this via 'dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy' in its configuration.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.findNewDatanode(DFSOutputStream.java:1036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.addDatanode2ExistingPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DFSOutputStream.java:1268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.processDatanodeError(DFSOutputStream.java:993)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:500)
---2018-01-30T15:15:15.015 INFO  [][][] [dal.locations.LocationsDataFramesHandler]
```